# Titan's Atmosphere

Tags: planetary-atmosphere, titan, atmospheric-escape

Is Titan's atmosphere being continually regenerated?  What is the current thinking on the origins and maintenance of Titan's atmosphere after the landing of the Huygens probe.

As I remember, atmospheric methane should be photochemically diminished by the sun in the few millions of years timeframe. One assumes that the liquid hydrocarbon features derive from the reacted methane. If so, is the hydrogen free to escape at Titan's atmospheric temperature?  From what source comes the methane?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1089/31410